# Clone 862D+ soldering iron heating element

Tags: resistance, soldering, heat, ceramic, iron-core

I purchased an ebay 862D+ rework station in 2017 and it has worked great.  Recently I broke the ceramic on the heating element but did not break the element itself so I was able to get ohm readings from my existing element.

I've attempted to order replacements twice but the elements I keep getting don't have even close to the same resistance.  I'm expecting about **1 ohm (sensor) and 15 ohms (heater)**, but the replacements I'm getting are about **3 ohms and 45 ohms**.  Where can I get direct replacements?  How close do the readings need to match?  Do the readings change as the element gets used over the years (i.e. are my readings off of the old element accurate)?

Thanks!

Comment: You did some measurements but you didn’t say whether the replacement works or not.  The low sensor resistance is that of a thermocouple. I wouldn’t worry about that. A 45ohm heater won’t heat anywhere near as well as the original one did. But try it first. Nothing will break if you do.

Comment: I wasn't able to get the replacement to work. I still haven't found a good replacement. Likely I will end up buying an all new soldering iron.

Answer (score 1):

> How close do the readings need to match?
> For the heater, if the resistance is more than your current model, it will take much longer to heat up. This would be something that you would want to be closely matched, within percents (like 5% or 10% at least )

For the temperature sensor, that has to match very well, it has to be the same type (thermocouple, RTD or thermistor). Odds are you have a thermocouple as they have low resistance, just knowing resistance won't help, you need to know they type of thermocouple. So it would be better to find the right model number of replacement.

> Do the readings change as the element gets used over the years (i.e.
> are my readings off of the old element accurate)?

For most heaters, no (unless you totally smoke them).